# Python: Print molecular weight for unambiguous DNA sequences while skipping ambiguous sequences

Tags: python, biopython, fasta, dna-sequence

I need to write a function that takes a file name (fasta file) as an argument, reads the sequences, and for each unambiguous sequence prints the sequence ID and its molecular weight. The fasta files contain both ambiguous and unambiguous sequences.

So far I have these two pieces of code that work separately alone. I don't know how to skip over the ambiguous sequences in the fasta file and only calculate molecular weight on the unambiguous sequences. Obviously it gives an error if I try because I've only entered values for ACGT and not the ambiguous ones. Can anyone help me figure out how to skip those sequences? Thanks!

Also, I don't understand how to combine them into one function, I've tried making 2 for loops for one function but it always gives errors. I think I would have to change the argument of the calc_mol_weight function to match the above seq_records but I don't understand how exactly to make them compatible.

```
seq_records = SeqIO.parse('short.fasta', 'fasta', alphabet=generic_dna)
seq_record_list = list(seq_records)
for seq_rec in seq_record_list:
    print(f'{seq_rec.id}')

def calc_mol_weight(sequence):   
    mol_weight = 0.0
    nucleotide_weights = {'A':331.2218, 'T':322.2085, 'C':307.1971, 'G':347.2212}
    for nucl in sequence:
        mol_weight += nucleotide_weights[nucl]
    return mol_weight
```

For reference - short.fasta:

```
>seq_7009 random sequence
DGRGGGWAVCVAACGTTGAT
>seq_418 random sequence
GAGCTGVTATST
>seq_9143_unamb random sequence
ACCGTTAAGCCTTAG
>seq_2888 random sequence
RVCCWDGARATAGBCGC
>seq_1101 random sequence
CSAATGYGATNBTA
>seq_107 random sequence
WGDGHGCDCTYANGTTWCA
>seq_6946 random sequence
TCVMBRAGRSGTCCAWA
>seq_6162 random sequence
YWBGCKTGCCAAGCGCDG
>seq_504 random sequence
ADDTAACCCTCTTKA
>seq_3535 random sequence
KKGTACACCAG
>seq_4077 random sequence
SRWSCRTTRVAGDCC
> seq_1626_unamb random sequence
GGATATTACCTA
```

Comment: I don't get how to calculate the weight of an ambiguous one. If we do not know the weight of `K`, then how are we supposed to calculate the weight?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You don't, since he said  > Can anyone help me figure out how to skip those sequences?

Answer (score 0):

To skip your ambiguous sequences, you have 2 solutions that come into my mind.

You could either use `if nucl in nucleotide_weigths`. It will check whether or not the character exists in the dictionnary. If it does, it will return `True` and you can evaluate this nucl element, and it will return `False` if the character is not found. You could then do :

```
if nucl not in nucleotide_weigths:
    break
```

So that it breaks the actual sequence if it is ambiguous.

The other option is to make a try/except block.

It basically works like this :

```
try:
    mol_weight += nucleotide_weights[nucl]
except:
    break
```

You can specify an error after the keyword except so it doesn't stop any errors coming (you don't want this), but what you need to know is : If an exception is raised (e.g : `ValueError, IndexError, KeyError, TypeError, ...`), the code in the `except block` will run. And so the break statement will get you out of your loop and this ambiguous sequence will be eluded. :)

---

As for your function needs, and double-loops I think the error comes from the first part where you'd have some errors trying to check a data you didn't have registered. If it's not the same, please post the code you tried for the double-loops and the traceback. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps: [@tfabiant](https://twitter.com/tfabiant), To run this code, in the terminal type: python script.py fastafile.fasta

```
def unambiguous(sequences):
    nucleotide_weights = {'A':331.2218, 'T':322.2085, 'C':307.1971, 'G':347.2212}
    for seq in sequences:
        seqname =  seq
        sequence = sequences[seq]
        weight = 0
        for nucleotide in sequence:
            if nucleotide not in nucleotide_weights:
                weight = "AMBIGUOUS"
                break
            else:
                weight+=nucleotide_weights[nucleotide]
        if weight != "AMBIGUOUS":
            print "%s\t\tWEIGHT %s"%(seqname, weight)
def readfasta():
    ##########I. Load Fasta File
    file = open(sys.argv[1])
    rfile = file.readline()
    seqs = {}
    ##########II. To Make fasta dictionary with the sequences
    tnv = ""#temporal name value
    while rfile != "":
        if ">" in rfile:
            tnv = string.strip(rfile)
            seqs[tnv] = ""
        else:
            seqs[tnv] += (string.strip(rfile)).upper()
        rfile = file.readline()
    return(seqs)

#To run this code, in the terminal: python readDNA.py fastafile.fasta
# OR insert this function in your code
import string, sys
sequences = readfasta()
unambiguous(sequences)
```